# Flash CS5 won't execute AS3 code

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am getting a strange issue in Flash CS5. I have a .fla file that was working fine up until recently. Now, when I Ctrl-Enter to Test Movie...nothing happens.

I have a Document Class set up (and when I click the pencil button, it opens up the right script, so Flash knows where the code is) called Main. In the constructor, there is a `trace('Main()')` just so I know the constructor got called, but that trace isn't showing up. A few days ago this same code was working fine, so i'm guessing I knocked around a setting or two in the IDE (not sure which, since Flash has the classpath set correctly)

Thanks in Advance,
-Esa

EDIT: Here's a worrying line from the Size report...Why is Actionscript Bytes '0'?

```
Scene      Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes  
-------    -----------    ----------    ------------------  
Scene 1              0             0                     0
```

EDIT 2: I also added a `trace` to the timeline, and that still doesn't show up (and ActionScript Bytes is still 0...the swf size hasn't actually changed even though I added the code).
Also I have restarted the program several times, and even restarted my computer (and did the 'Delete ASO' thing that Mattias suggested). No dice.

Comment: The IDE obviously is not running the swf. You probably remapped the keys. Try running the browser I think the key commands are cntl+shift+enter

Comment: I have exported the movie as a swf and run it in a browser (checking the Flash log for traces), same issue. The swf window pops up. It's the correct size and has the correct background color and the objects on stage in the first (and only) frame are there. But nothing else happens in the output box.

Comment: I just added a second frame slightly different to the first, and the swf plays both frames (alternating back and forth quickly). Afterwards, I a `stop()` on the first frame and it is ignored.

Comment: usually when the swf just runs through the frames and nothing else it is because there is an error in the code at this time no code will execute at all so no traces will work.

Comment: I'm not getting any compiler errors though. Is there another error log that I should be checking? Doesn't make sense, since this exact code has compiled before.

Comment: If you can try it on someone else's machine with Flash CS5. Failing that you might have to do a repair installation of Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying only the files you need (`.as`, `.fla`) into a different folder and recompile. If a big project has too many files within the main directory I think it just gets tired midway while compiling

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Flash lost the connection to the document class.

**First try to remove the cache:**

1. Control -> Delete ASO
2. Hit Ctrl-Enter

**If it still does not work:**

1. Remove the document class and hit Ctrl-Enter.
2. Add the document class again and give it a new try.

If it still does not work, try changing to an other Document Class to see if that works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sigh. None of those options worked for me. Still nothing. I even added a trace to the timeline, and no dice. :/

Comment: Try File -> Save and Compact then. And you don´t get any compile errors at all?

Comment: No Compile errors...I don't have Save and Compact as a Menu option, though.

Comment: Ok. Maybe they removed it in CS5. Try copying your content into a new fla.

Comment: That's going to be a bit. However, any fla I throw at it (including ones I have created months ago with this same version of Flash) has the same problem.

Comment: close all open projects. go to preferences then actionscript then settings make sure you have the sdk path correct. I am at work and looking at CS4 so can't be exact for CS5 should be something like $(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flex_sdk_3/

Comment: How big is the filesize of your FLA, Esaevian?

Comment: @bigp The Fla is 45K (only has a few assets, the code loads in separate swfs with the actual content)

Comment: @The_asMan The sdk seems to be set up right: $(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/flex_sdk/4.0.0/

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the FLA is set to AS3 (and not AS2) ?