# Actionscript not included in Flash CS5 swf compile

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Whenever I compile a swf in Flash, nothing happens. No traces, no compile errors, nothing. The swf that is produces is severely limited in size (several times smaller than the file with Actionscript), leading me to believe that Flash is outright ignoring the code.

Is there a way to get Flash to recognize Actionscript again?

Using Flash CS5 on Mac OSX 10.6.8

My other thread that has more information (but no answers), if you need it: [Flash CS5 won't execute AS3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599542/flash-cs5-wont-execute-as3-code)

Here's some of the code:

Frame 1:

```
trace('Hello World: Frame'); //doesn't trace
```

And in the document class, Main.as

```
public class Main extends Movieclip
{
    public function Main()
    {
        trace("Hello World: Doc"); //doesn't trace
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);       
    }

    public function onAdded(e:Event)
    {
        trace("Main: onAdded()");
        //more stuff about loading in external content
        //this function never gets run, since the constructor doesn't get run.
    }
}
```

**ANSWER FOUND** See Plastic Sturgeon's comment. It involved a regrettable reinstall of the entire Flash CS5 app, as well as wiping out my preferences while uninstalling. Seems like the preference file just got corrupted. Hope this won't happen after another year of use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash CS5 won't execute AS3 code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599542/flash-cs5-wont-execute-as3-code)

Comment: @shanethehat How is marking this a 'possible duplicate' helpful if a) that post has no correct answers and b) I obviously know about that question, since I asked it and I referenced it in my post?

Comment: The preferred approach is to update your existing question with more info. Whenever you edit the question it will get bumped back up the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a silly question but did you set the Document Class in the .FLA?

Comment: Yup. There's a Document class (I click the pencil and it opens up the correct file) and some test `trace()` calls on the first frame. But there is no output. Just an empty swf.

Comment: Posted. It's super simple. It also seems localized to my machine, others can run the file.

Comment: If other people can run it, the problem is not with the code, but with the install of Flash on your computer. Uninstall and reinstall flash (The Application, not just the flash player).

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon Any other ideas? The office is currently sitting upside down as we look for it. Edit: But yes, I am prepared to do a reinstall as soon as we find that damn disc!

Comment: You can also try creating a new FLA and pointing the Document Class to the .AS file again but if that doesn't work I'm going to have to agree with Plastic Sturgeon... time for a clean install.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon Found the CD, reinstalled a few times (I had to wipe out my preferences, the first reinstall came with the same problem). And it works! Sad that it had to come to a complete reinstall. Time to completely rebuild my workspaces...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the flash debugger.  Install the Netscape-compatable content debugger if you use Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc... Install the ActiveX control content debugger if you use IE for testing.  This is required if you use Flash Builder, anyway. Not sure about Flash CS.

[ADOBE FLASH PLAYER 11 — 32 BIT DEBUGGER](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

EDIT: As an alternative, you can try using ExternalInterface to make sure your code is working correctly. This can help with troubleshooting your system. Here's a tutorial: [Debugging in ActionScript 3.0 – Part 1 – Trace Tutorial](http://www.flashdev.ca/article/debugging-as3/)

Comment: I am already using the debug player/remote debug sessions. It doesn't even connect to Flash (other swfs do).

ExternalInterface doesn't work because the code isn't being run (or included in the swf) in the first place.